# How to delete from map all records with same value but different keys?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have `boost::unordered_map<int, Animal*>` and I need to delete all inserts where value is the same pointer like `Animal* a;` ( **a** is given **Animal*** like parameter, I have for different keys in map same **Animal*** pointer on couple places).

```
boost::unordered_map<int, Animal*> mp;
Animal* rex = new Animal("Rex");
mp[1]=rex;
mp[2]=rex;
mp[9]=rex;
```

How to delete all records where value is rex, and after that delete rex from heap only once ?

Comment: Since maps are optimized in one-way (key-to-value). In your case, you have to iterate through all items and remove them one by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list and delete the records that match the pointer value you are searching for.

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<int, Animal*> AnimalMap;
AnimalMap mp;

void DeleteStuff(Animal* searchPointerValue)
{
    for(AnimalMap::iterator it = mp.begin(); it < mp.end(); )
    {
        if(it->second == searchPointerValue)
        {
            // erase() invalidates the iterator but returns a new one
            // that points to the next element in the map.
            it = mp.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it; // Only bump the iterator if no erase is done
                  // since unordered_map::erase() takes care of that for us
        }
    }

    // now we can delete the animal as you so desire
    delete searchPointerValue;
}
```

Comment: This will cause memory leak - nothing `delete`s `Animal*`

Comment: @Kiril We don't see how they are created, who knows how they should be deleted?

Comment: @PeterWood - what do you mean? It's shown in the question: `Animal* rex = new Animal("Rex");`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - "How to delete all records where value is rex, and **after that delete rex from heap only once**"

Comment: @Kiril I meant in the answer, not the question. I think we're all clear now (c:

Answer (score 2):

Use smart pointer, like `boost::shared_ptr`, instead of raw pointer. This will give you the chance to remove the elements from the map without any concerns.

Having a smart pointer with reference counting, you can simply iterate over the map and erase each element, which have the value, you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<int, Animal*> mapType;
mapType myMap;

mapType::iterator it = myMap.begin();
while(it != myMap.end())
{
    if(it->second == current_pointer)
        it = mp.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}

delete  current_pointer;  // Don't forget this
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a suitable functor?

```
std::remove_if(std::begin(mp), std::end(mp),
               [](const std::pair<int, Animal*>& pair)
               { return (pair.second == rex); });
```

Of course this might cause memory leaks unless you do `delete rex`. Using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) is a good idea.

Comment: According to [cpp reference] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) it is not possible to use remove_if with associative containers.